# Ext.Data.Store получить значение из переменной (массива)

Tags: массивы, extjs

Не могу понять, как мне загрузить в `Ext.Data.Store` значение из переменной, в интернете не нашел работающего варианта, да и вообще какой пример не посмотри, везде по разному написано.
Вот весь `ext js` код:

```
        var adrs = '<?php echo $json; ?>'; //get data

    Ext.define('Addresses', { //model
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        idProperty: 'id',

        fields: [{
            name: 'ID',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'IP',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'Comment',
            type: 'date'
        }]
  });

   var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Addresses',
        data: adrs,
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader(adrs)
            }

    });

   Ext.onReady(function(){

   Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Addresses',
    height: 200,
    width: 350,
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        header: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id'
    }, {
        header: 'IP',
        dataIndex: 'ipAddress'
    }, {
        header: 'Comment',
        dataIndex: 'comment'
    }],
    renderTo: 'ipGrid'
});
```

});

На странице рисуется `grid`, но он пустой.. я не понимаю почему, думаю что именно в `Ext.Data.Store` ошибка, т.к. я вообще почти наугад там написал, т.к. не понимаю как надо

*п.с. я только начинаю изучать ext js, поэтому многого еще не понимаю*

Comment: неужели никто не знает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader(adrs)
```

Если у вас `JSON`, а вы пытаетесь прочесть при помощи не `JsonReader` а при помощи `ArrayReader`, то тут уж можно предположить что не ту функцию используете.
Также попробуйте в объявлении `columns` вместо header указать `text`. 
Убедитесь также что `var adrs` строится верно. Плюс вроде в указании  `Store` для вас необязательно делать параметр `autoload`. 
Ну вроде высказался полностью по поводу моих предположений.